# Signal magnitude area

Tags: signal-analysis

I'm confused by the SMA. I'm reading a paper which states that "SMA is the square root of the summation of the filtered acceleration signal". So I understand that it's $sma = \sqrt{\sum{samples}}$

I check the referenced paper, which says that "SMA is calculated after dividing area under the acceleration curve with the time interval". So $sma = {1 \over T} \sum samples$, which is some kind of average, which looks like what is on this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702753/matlab-compute-normalized-signal-magnitude-area) question.

And the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_magnitude_area) is so new I'm not sure it's reliable.

In the end, what is exactly SMA as I couldn't find a proper definition online?

Comment: `SMA is calculated after dividing area under the acceleration curve with the time interval` means that $sma$ is computed **from** the quantity $\frac 1T\sum \text{samples}$, and _not necessarily_ that $sma$ **equals** $\frac 1T\sum \text{samples}$

Comment: Does anyone knows functions in python to calculate SMA, SVM (signal vector magnitude) and PSD (Power Spectral Density) please? Thanks you

Comment: @Ziad Welcome to SE.SP.  Please do not add answers that are not answers. If you have a question, [please ask a new question.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a proper definition thanks to the following article:
http://www.rehab.research.va.gov/jour/2013/509/jrrd-2012-12-0233.html

This is what I've edited Wikipedia with:
$$f_{sma}= {1 \over {T}} {\int_{0}^{T} |x(t)-a_x|+|y(t)-a_y|+|z(t)-a_z| dt}$$

(It wasn't because of text-search but images-search. Algorithms are sometimes surprising)

Answer (score 0):

For a discrete signal in three dimensions (maybe a triaxial accelerometer sampled) the algorithm to compute SMA is:

```
    //Signal magnitude area
    public double sma(double[] x, double[] y, double[] z){
        double sum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++)
            sum += (Math.abs(x[i]) + Math.abs(y[i]) + Math.abs(z[i]));
        return sum /x.length;
    }
```

Where `mean()` is a function to compute the mean of the array and where we assume the arrays to have the same length.

**EDIT:** I created this function starting from the definition here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_magnitude_area

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a reference that backs up the definition that you use.